# Add Parent to UIElement in C#

Tags: c#, image, silverlight, xaml, uielement

Is it possible to add a parent to the `UIElement` in C#? I know it's possible to do it with children like this:

```
(AssociatedObject as Grid).Children.Add(imageObject);
```

I can't find any way to set the parent of a `UIElement`, and can't find very much on Google either.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. What do you really need this for?

Comment: Parent is readonly and it is implied when you add to the Children collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. The [`UIElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) class actually doesn't support adding a Parent or Children.

Your example uses the [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) class (which does, in fact, allow you to add children). You'd have to add the child element to the parent element using the parent's children collection (assuming the parent is of a type that allows adding children).